# how to use printf on the command line?

Tags: command-line

I wanted to try using a simple printf on terminal to see if i can directly program on it , but didn't work; I wrote on it these 2 lines:

```
~$ #include<stdio.h>
~$ printf("E");
```

and it says

bash: syntax error near unexpected token '"E"'

I don't see anything wrong...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your shell isn't a C interpreter - it has its own syntax, and its own `printf` function, which aside from inheriting many of the format specifiers from the C function is quite separate

Valid forms are

```
printf 'E\n'
```

or

```
printf '%c\n' E
```

There is no equivalent of the `#include` directive (which would just be an - ignored - comment as far as the shell is concerned)

---

If you want to actually write a small C program from the command line, you can do that with `cat` using a *here document*:

```
$ cat > main.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Terminate your input py pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. Then you can compile the program using `gcc`:

```
gcc -o my_first_prog main.c
```

and finally run it from the shell

```
$ ./my_first_prog 
Hello world!
```

Comment: this is quite silly then, my professor was teaching about the "main" function arguments and wrote on the blackboard a C program with main taking 2 ints from the terminal...saying it could all be written on the shell but i guess it's a lie then

Comment: @wattbatt perhaps a misunderstanding: you can certainly *write* a C program from the command line - however you can't expect the Bash shell to interpret and run it.

Comment: @wattbatt I have added what I imagine your professor had in mind

Comment: @wattbatt "but i guess it's a lie then" – apparently you're a newbie with shell and C programming, that's fine, everyone starts as a newbie. But please stop for a moment and think about the probability of your professor knowing something fundamental incorrectly or even telling straight lies, versus you misunderstanding something.